# ExpressionEngine with CartThrob Paypal return error

Tags: add-on, cartthrob, paypal-express-checkout

Clients are not being redirected to the return parameter on the checkout form on CartThrob on EE after sales completion from PayPal. Error states that "the page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies"

This does not only happens to me while testing the cart, it also happens to actual customers.. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks..

Comment: One real quick idea, having no experience with cartthrob at all:  Is there a discrepancy between the checkout page being https and the return page being http?  That can sometimes cause cookie weirdness.

Comment: Up to date with CartThrob? (note devotee version sometimes lags so best to get from CT site) - there was a fix for a Paypal redirect bug in the latest....